# Passing Delegate through multiple hierarchy

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I wrote a custom class, TagsScrollView, which displays tags inside a scroll view.

When the tags are pressed, TagsScrollView relies on its delegate to implement what to do. Almost all the time, this involves:

1. Changing the tab index to another index
2. Pushing TagsDetailVC to the current navigation controller.

Right now, this is how my app is structured:

[image]

Dotted line indicates a "has" relationship. MainVC has a FeedView, which has a few FeedCellViews, which in turn has a TagsScrollView each.

Solid line indicates a "push" relationship. ImageDetailVc is pushed onto the navController of MainVC.

How can I organize my code such that TagsScrollView's delegate can be pointed at MainVC elegantly?

right now I have defined the following:

**TagsScrollView.h**

```
@protocol TagPressedDelegate<NSObject>
@required
- (void)tagPressed:(id)sender forQuery:(NSString *)query;
@end
```

**FeedCellView.m**

`self.tagsScrollView.tagPressedDelegate = self.tagPressedDelegate`

**FeedView.m**

`self.cells[0].tagPressedDelegate = self.tagPressedDelegate`

**MainViewVC.m**

```
self.feed.tagPressedDelegate = self
....

- (void)tagPressed...
```

How can I avoid this pattern? What can I do better? Should I have TagsScrollViewDelegate extend ScrollViewDelegate instead?

Comment: Have you considered using a notification instead of a delegate?

Answer (score 0):

You can definitely do better, remove the delegation pattern, use blocks.

Add a block based property to your TagsScrollView .h file

`@property (copy, nonatomic) void (^tagPressedBlock)(id sender, NSString *query);`

in the .m file add the related callbacks

```
- (void)tagPressed:(id)sender {
  if (_tagPressedBlock) {
    _tagPressedBlock(sender, self.query); // I'm assuming that the query is your iVar
  }
}
```

assign the property like this

```
tagsScrollView.tagPressedBlock = ^(id sender, NSString *query) {
  // do stuff with those parameters
}
```

That's for "doing it better"

As for how to pass a tag pressed event to your `MainVC` class, you should use NSNotificationCenter.

Define the notification name somewhere globally visible, for instance I'd suggest creating a Defines.h file and #including it in your Prefix.pch file.

Anyway, define the notification name:

`static NSString *const TagPressedNotification = @"TagPressedNotification";`

Next publish that notification when the `-tagPressed:` is executed and encapsulate the valuable information into the userInfo dictionary:

```
- (void)tagPressed:(id)sender {
  [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:TagPressedNotification object:nil userInfo:@{@"sender" : sender, @"query" : self.query, @"scrollView" : self.tagScrollView}];
  //.. code 
}
```

Next add your `MainVC` as an observer to that notification:

MainVC.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
  [super viewDidLoad];
  [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                           selector:@selector(tagPressed:)
                                               name:TagPressedNotification
                                             object:nil];
}
```

And implement `-tagPressed:` method in your MainVC

```
- (void)tagPressed:(NSNotification *)notification {
  id sender = notification.userInfo[@"sender"];
  NSString *query = notification.userInfo[@"query"];
  TagScrollView *scrollView = notification.userInfo[@"scrollView"];
  if (scrollView == myScrollView) { // the one on your mainVC
    // do stuff
  }
}
```

Add don't forget to clean yourself out of NotificationCenter's register:

```
- (void)dealloc {
  [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
}
```

easy

edit

I suppose you should also pass the scroll view, which is the sender, since your mainVC contains that scroll view as well. Edited the code

Another edit

Create an enumeration define in your Defines.h file

```
enum {
  TagSenderTypeFeed = 1,
  TagSenderTypeImageDetail
};
typedef NSInteger TagSenderType;
```

When creating a notification add appropriate enum value to your notification's userInfo dictionary `@"senderType" : @(TagSenderTypeFeed)`

Comment: Hey good answer. So if I do the broadcast in TagsScrollView, how can I differentiate which VC will react? MainVC only knows about FeedView and ImageDetailVC knows TagsScrollView directly.

Comment: actually can I just recursively check the superview to see if it's a particular VC's view? that should be able to work

Comment: That's way worse then what I've suggested, don't be lazy, do it the right way

Comment: The problem is that my tagsScrollView wouldn't know what the enumType because I am not always able to specify that directly. In my diagram, only ImageDetailVC can do this. There is no way for TagsScrollView on the MainVC stack to know about this unless MainVC goes through multiple layers to let it know about this, which is again like the tagsPressedDelegate pattern I have come across before.

Comment: @tc. geh... sometimes sarcastic comments have an awful lot of positive influence... I now know how to properly work with blocks and how to avoid retain cycles... thanks man